# Can $n\times n$ matrix have algebraic multiplicity less than $n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I can't seem to think of an example that would have an algebraic multiplicity less than $n$.

Comment: The degree of the characteristic polynomial is always $n$, so [in an algebraically closed field] the sum of the algebraic multiplicities of the eigenvalues is always $n$.

Comment: (1) Please put the  question you are asking in the body of the post, not just the subject line. (2) Matrices don't have algebraic multiplicity, so the question does not parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p$ is a polynomial and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, then *algebraic multiplicity* of $\lambda$ is the maximum number of times the factor $(t-\lambda)$ appears when $p$ is decomposed into linear factors.

Thus, applying 'algebraic multiplicity' to matrices is not appropriate.

The degree of the *characteristic polynomial* of an $n$-by-$n$ matrix over an algebraically closed field (like $\mathbb{C}$) is always $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean the total number of eigenvalues of a given matrix over a given Field as the algebraic multiplicity of a matrix, consider
$$
\begin {pmatrix}
0&-1\\
1&0\\
\end {pmatrix}
$$
This matrix has no eigenvalues in the real Field. As already pointed out, the concept of algebraic multiplicity for a matrix does not exist.